# Can't configure "database shared throughput" on cosmosdb with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

**My context**

Trying to deploy azure cosmosdb (MongoDB) with Terraform.

I need to configure database shared throughput.

**My issues**

I can't figure out how to do this, I don't even know if it is supported.

I tried this:

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "cosmosdb" {
  name                                  = "mycosmosdb1
  resource_group_name                   = "rg1"
  location                              = "westeurope"
  offer_type                            = "Standard"
  kind                                  = "MongoDB"      
  mongo_server_version                  = "4.2"

   capacity {
     total_throughput_limit = 1000
   }

  capabilities {
    name = "EnableMongo"
  }
  capabilities {
    name = "DisableRateLimitingResponses"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_database" "cosmosdb_mongo_database" {
  name = "db1"

  resource_group_name = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.resource_group_name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.name
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_collection" "cosmosdb_mongo_collection" {
  database_name       = "db1"
  name                = "col1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.resource_group_name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.name

  index {
    keys   = ["_id"]
    unique = false
  }
}
```

But no impact.

**What I need**

- Is it currently supported by azurerm ?
- How I can do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to configure "database shared throughput" on cosmosdb with Terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

In the configuration you provided you have set up the throughput in the wrong resource. To configure shared throughput for a database, you should not use `azurerm_cosmosdb_account`, but a different resource.

To configure shared throughput for a CosmosDB MongoDB database, you should set the `throughput` attribute in the `azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_database` resource. The `throughput` setting is not part of the `azurerm_cosmosdb_account` resource.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "cosmosdb" {
  name                = "vkcosmosdb1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "MongoDB"
  mongo_server_version = "4.2"

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "Session"
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }

  capabilities {
    name = "EnableMongo"
  }

  capabilities {
    name = "DisableRateLimitingResponses"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_database" "cosmosdb_mongo_database" {
  name                = "vkdb1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.resource_group_name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.name
  throughput          = 1000
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_collection" "cosmosdb_mongo_collection" {
  name                = "vkcol1"
  database_name       = azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_database.cosmosdb_mongo_database.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.resource_group_name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.name

  index {
    keys   = ["_id"]
    unique = false
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]